# How to change name of relationships created by dbicdump

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have a couple of tables like:

- user
- user_address -> with fk to users

And I'm generating my dbic schema using dbicdump.
This creates the following relationship in User.pm:

```
__PACKAGE__->has_many( 
  "user_addresses", 
  "World::DBIC::Result::UserAddress", 
  { "foreign.user_id" => "self.id" }, 
  { cascade_copy => 0, cascade_delete => 0 },
);
```

Is it possible to change the name of the relationship to something like "addresses"? How?
(I meant without changing the code before # DO NOT MODIFY THIS OR ANYTHING ABOVE!)

If not, is there any way to make an alias to the relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at rel_name_map in [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::Base](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema%3a%3aLoader%3a%3aBase#rel_name_map).  You should be able to do something like this when you create your schema:

```
my %args = ( 
    use_moose      => 1,
    use_namespaces => 1,
    rel_name_map   => { user_addresses => 'addresses' },
    # more args here...
);

make_schema_at( 'My::Schema', \%args, [ $connect_arg ... ] );
```

The rel_name_map is the important one, but I've added a few more lines for context.